# Missing Property of this in Vue component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have simple Vue form component, written in TypeScript. It works when I run it, but is doesn't type-check. It says that the `property 'title' is not present on the enclosing object type`, which is of course true, since it's a `v-model` reference. Am I doing something wrong? or is it just too match magic for TypeScript to handle? The error occurs on the following line:

```js
body: JSON.stringify({ title: this.title, done: false }),
```

This is the whole component:

```html
<template>
    <form>
        <label>
            Title
            <input type="text" v-model="title">
        </label>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" v-on:click="submitData()">
    </form>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
    name: "TodoForm",
    data: function () {
        return { title: "" }
    },
    methods: {
        submitData: function() {
            fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/todo/', {
                method: "POST",
                headers: new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/json"}),
                body: JSON.stringify({ title: this.title, done: false }),
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: could you reproduce the error on a sandbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Vue CLI [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Basic-Usage) state:

> To let TypeScript properly infer types inside Vue component options, you need to define components with `Vue.component` or `Vue.extend`

So, it should look similar to this:

```html
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  data() {
    return {
      title: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitData() {
      console.log(this.title)
    }
  }
})
</script>
```